# CSS3 - Color item based on certain condition

Tags: css

I have a table with a column "amount". If the item in the cell is positive I want it to be colored in green, if not in red.

This can be done very easily using jQuery but I wondered if there's any trick using new CSS3 features that could help me achieve this without using javascript at all.

Is this possible?

Comment: This cannot be done using only CSS3.

Comment: You **need** to use Javascript for this if you can't modify the html. If you can modify the HTML, do the value check on the server side and add a css class for green and red.

Comment: How do you understand if the item cell is positive? Can you add class to the element when it's positive?

Comment: I didn't think it was possible but wanted to check anyway. Here is the js code I used in the end:
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".amount").each(function() {
      $(this).addClass($(this).html() >= 0 ? "positive" : "negative");
    });
});

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can arrange for the server to generate HTML with `data-*` attributes containing the value. Then:

```
<span data-value="-123">-123</span>

[data-value^="-"] {
    color: red;
}
```

In words, "if the value of the `data-value` attribute starts with a minus sign, color the text red."

Another idea is to use the `:invalid` pseudo-class. This will only work for an `input` element, unfortunately. However, you can disable it to prevent input and style it so it looks like regular text. You will also have to arrange to have the value placed in the `value` attribute of the `input` element:

```
<!-- specify a pattern which permits only positive numbers -->
<input type="text" pattern="\\d*" value="-123" disabled>

input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

Neither of these approaches is ideal; you'll probably end up using JS.

Answer (score 0):

When you return the data for the table, you will need to add a class to the TD for your amount column for any value is less than 0. You could use "negative" and give this a style of colour:RED; You can set the default style for the amount column TD as green for all positive values, and when the browser encounters the "negative" style it will set negative values to be red.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
<style>

.positive
{
background:green;
}

.negative
{
background:red;
}

</style>

<script>

function colorBackground(){

if (document.getElementById('yourid').value < 0){

document.getElementById('yourid').style.bgColor = "red";
}else {
document.getElementById('yourid').style.bgColor = "green";
}
}

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Apparently this can't be done using CSS3 only.

Here is the jQuery code I used in the end:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".amount").each(function() {
      $(this).addClass($(this).text() >= 0 ? "positive" : "negative");
    });
});
```

If anyone has any shorter version of it, I'd be happy to have it :)

Thanks

Comment: Personally I would use .text() instead of .html() as text will return only the text value where as .html() will return any text and any HTML that wraps or sits in line with the text. In the future for example, if you add mark-up around the text you won't need to update your script.